# Weird output from a function that calls from an imported function

Tags: python, function, random, import

I have this code here:

```
import random
def AI():
    choices = ["rock","paper","scissor"]
    return str(random.choice(choices))
print(AI)
```

That prints out:

```
function AI at 0x0000000003527378
```

instead of either `rock`, `paper` or `scissor`.

When I do it in the shell or outside of a function, it returns and prints normally, but not in a function. I'm new to Python, so this is very confusing to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function by placing `()` after it:

```
print(AI())
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> import random
>>> def AI():
...     choices = ["rock","paper","scissor"]
...     return str(random.choice(choices))
...
>>> print(AI)
<function AI at 0x0236CFA8>
>>> print(AI())
rock
>>>
```

---

Also, wrapping `random.choice(choices)` in `str` is not necessary.  The below code will work fine:

```
return random.choice(choices)
```